# windows server (standard) licence more than 16 cores. How it works?

Tags: license, licensing

Hy!

How does windows server additional core licence works? My server has 2 CPU 16core/CPU. So I need to buy a licence for 32 core. Server 2019 standard licence (P73-07791) good for 16 core. I still have to buy a licence for 16 core.

1. can I buy the same type of licence for this?
2. OR do I need to buy a different type of licence for this?

thanks,
F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is correct, you have to purchase, in this case, two 16-pack core licenses.
Quick reference [here](https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/C/E/7CED6910-C7B2-4196-8C55-208EE0B427E2/Windows_Server_2019_licensing_datasheet_EN_US.pdf).

Also, check whether the services you are going to provide with your Windows servers do require [CALs or MLs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/licensing/product-licensing/client-access-license) for clients, as they likely do.